# Detect whether user is in car/bus/train using Google Activity Recognition (React Native)

Tags: react-native, activity-recognition

I am making a React Native app which uses Google Activity Recognition. Currently It only detects activity as IN_VEHICLE when user is in car, train or bus etc. I want to differentiate between it, i.e., I want to know whether user is in car, train or bus.

Is it possible right now? If yes, how to implement it in React Native app?